# Implements interface with specific event

Tags: java, events, interface

I am newbie in Java and created an `interface`. I am then trying to implement specific event of this interface. For eg. my interface is:

```
public interface PlayerListener {
    public void onNext();

    public void onPrevious();

}
```

What I would like to do is implement specific event only instead of entire interface like this:

```
public class myClass implements PlayerListener.onNext {

}
```

But my current coding is only allowing me to include complete interface instead of specific event.

How can I make it possible?

Comment: Which Java version you're using? Java 8 does have this feature not earlier versions.

Comment: I am using Java 8. There are some other builtin interfaces which I can use like this but what I implemented is not possible. For eg. I can use `implements MediaPlayer.onErrorListener`

Comment: What you want is an Adapter. That is a class that implements the interface with "standard" (mostly no-op) implementations of all methods of the interface. You can then extend this Adapter in your class, overriding only the methods you need.

Comment: "I have declared this interface inside a class like this: `public class myClass { interface playerListener { public void onNext(); public void onPrevious(); } }`" - That's different now. As is, this is just an interface your class is defining. You'll need to implement it and call `onNext()` on an instance of the implementing class.

Comment: Make 2 separate interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

rather than making an interface, try making a class instead. the class could have all the default code for the "interface" methods. for example:

```
    public class PlayerListener {

    public void onNext(){
        //Default Code
    }

    public void onPrevious()
        //Default Code
    }
```

rather than implementing an interface, just extend this class.

```
    public class myClass extends PlayerListener{
        @Override
        public void onNext(){
            //Code for method
        }
    }
```

the "@Override" is to make sure you are actually changing a method from your extended class. (If you don't have the correct method name or some other mistake then it will give a warning in the console)